# Download tracks from Soundcloud via their API

Tags: php, api, mp3, soundcloud

I have around 1000 liked tracks on Soundcloud and I'd like to download the ones available for download.

Is it possible to use the API to download these where a download option is available?

Thanks for any pointers :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. its possible.

1. Send a request to `/users/{id}/favorites` here `id` is your user id. it'll return all of your favorite tracks.
2. For each tracks

   1. Check the `downloadable` property's value. if this property is not available request to `/tracks/{id}` to get all the properties of tracks.
   2. If `downloadable` is true download it from url found on `download_url` property.

View [Reference](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks)

Comment: Hi @shiplu, have you done this before? I'd love to see an example if possible?

Answer (score 0):

This will be easier if you use this [SoundCloud Downloader](https://vidfrom.com/soundcloud-downloader/). This tool supports you to download instantly or listen directly on the web.

Watch the video to see how to use it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MB2PZl1KvtY

**Steps to download tracks on SoundCloud:**

**Step 1:** Choose a song you love on SoundCloud. Then click the share button.

**Step 2:** You should be able to see Copy Link option there.

**Step 3:** Go back SoundCloud Downloader. Then, paste the music link into the text box.

**Step 4:** Click Start and waiting for the downloader to fetch MP3 files or music playlist. Then, right click the download button and choose “Save link as…” or “Download link as…” to save the Mp3 file.

Comment: I don't think a manual Downloader is of any use for someone who is trying to find a way to use the Soundcloud API to mass download tracks. Maybe if the downloader itself had an API it could help but I don't believe it has one

Comment: The API will limit downloads per day. So I think the best solution is to use the Downloader, you can have multiple tabs open if you want to download all the songs in the player.

Comment: I think you missunderstand the idea. API allows automation, a downloader doesn't. If you're willing to download 1000 songs, you are probably looking for a way to mass download them all without manually clicking through every single one of them.